# Is Griffiths simply wrong here? (Electrostatic Boundary Conditions)

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, gauss-law, boundary-conditions

[image: **enter image description here**]

In the above illustration, shouldn't $E_{above}$ and $E_{below}$ be in opposite directions? If not, how did Griffiths end up the following equation? From the above directions, shouldn't the flux add up?

Comment: I read the title of the question, and my instinctive response was "No". :P

Comment: In my opinion, the diagram and notation are a little ambiguous.  The electric field on either side can point either away from the material or toward it, all depending on what else is going on (i.e. what other charges there might be that are setting up this electric field). I think to make this completely non-ambiguous, just think of the perpendicular-signs as $x$, $y$, or $z$, i.e. the fields are actually the *components* of the electric field above and below. Generally, if $\hat{n}$ is a unit vector perpendicular to the surface pointing from the below side to the above side...

Comment: ...then the boundary condition reads $(\vec{E}_{\textrm{above}} - \vec{E}_{\textrm{below}})\cdot\hat{n} = \sigma/\epsilon_0$.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Two ways of seeing that it’s right:

1. Consider the case of no charge. Then nothing interesting is happening at the sheet, so the fields should be equal: both sides of the equation are zero.
2. Gaus’s law: the sum of the fields going *away*, which is the *outward* flux, is given by the charge. Since $E_{below}$ is defined as towards the charge, it enters that calculation with a minus sign.

He’s picked a sign convention where the field upward is positive everywhere. That means that $E_{below}$ is *defined* such that a positive value means "the E vector points up" and a negative value means "the E vector points down".  Which way the E vector points is given by the physics:

- if there's positive charge on the surface and no external field, the E field below it will point down, hence $E_{below}$ will have a negative value.
- If there's a large upward going external field, then in that case the E field points upward everywhere, and $E_{below}$ will be positive.

To put it another way, the length of the $E_{below}$ arrow in the picture isn't showing you the absolute magnitude; that has to come from somewhere else and is written as "$E_{below}$", a number.  And it's not even showing you the direction, because if $E_{below}$ is less than zero, the actual E vector is pointing the other way.  That arrow there is just defining a direction, like $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ and $\hat{z}$.

Comment: Sir, Could you please explain why $E_{below}$ is directed upwards?

Comment: Added a bit more at the bottom of the answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Your argument is that the arrows only give the sign convention. Why would it take **two** arrows to indicate this? $E_{below}$ points downward for positive $\sigma$. The illustration is wrong. The equation is also wrong as it is stated in terms of the magnitudes of $\bf E$, and these are equal. The equation cannot mean that the difference of the vectors is $\sigma/\epsilon_0$ as $\sigma$ is not a vector.

Comment: E_below depends on both the charge in the surface PLUS any external applied field. Depending on the relative size, it can be positive upward or positive downward (I.e. negative upward)

Answer (score 4):

Griffiths in correct.  The flux through the top portion of the box is not just $E_{\small{top}}^\top$ but actually $\vec E\cdot (A\vec n) $ where $\hat n$ is perpendicular to the surface and points out: in your diagram, $\hat n$ would be along $+{\hat z}$ for the top portion of the flux calculation.

For the bottom of the box the $\hat n$ vector points along $-\hat z$ so the flux through through those sides of the box work out to 
$$
(E_{\small{top}}^{\top} - E_{\small{bottom}}^\top)A \tag{1}
$$
when $\vec E_{\small{bottom}}$ points along $+\hat z$: the minus sign in (1) comes from the $-\hat z$ for the direction of the surface element $d\vec A$ at the bottom of the box.

Thus, ignoring the thin sides of the box because the flux through those is arbitrarily small, you have 
$$
(E_{\small{top}}^{\top} - E_{\small{bottom}}^\top)A=\frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \sigma A
$$
and the area cancels out.

Comment: Thanks, I totally get how he ended up with the equation. Could you please explain why $E_{below}$ is directed upwards?

Comment: well surely it must be so else, as $\sigma\to 0$, the field would not be continuous.

Answer (score 2):

The illustration and the equation may be confusing. It corresponds to a situation with an **external field** pointing upward that is larger than that due to $\sigma$. However the two arrows are of the same length, so if this were intended then $\sigma=0$. If there is no such field then $E_{above}$ and $E_{below}$ point in opposite directions and their magnitudes should be added, not subtracted.

Answer (score 0):

To support that Griffiths is correct, I would start with quoting from Bob Jacobsen's answer:

> He’s picked a sign convention where the field upward is positive everywhere. That means that $E_{below}$ is defined such that a positive value means "the E vector points up" and a negative value means "the E vector points down".

Adding to this, I would also consider the convention that the direction of the area vector is positive along the upward direction and vice-versa.

Now, let's start from Gauss' law which says that $\boxed{Q_{enc}=\Phi\cdot\epsilon_0}$, where $Q_{enc}$ is the charge enclosed by the Gaussian pillbox and $\Phi$ is the electric flux.

Applying this to the Gaussian pillbox in the figure, we can write
\begin{align*}
Q_{enc} &=\epsilon_0\left[(E_{above}^\perp)\cdot(A)+(E_{below}^\perp)\cdot(-A)\right]\\ \implies\sigma A&=\epsilon_0A\left[E_{above}^\perp-E_{below}^\perp\right]\\ \implies\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0}&=E_{above}^\perp-E_{below}^\perp
\end{align*}

Note that the area vector along $E_{above}^\perp$ is positive and the area vector along $E_{below}^\perp$ is negative due to the chosen convention.